# myFunction is not defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried using the jQuery SRC for my code. However, it returns an error stating that `myFunction` is not defined. Without the SRC, it can run just fine without any problems. Here is the code:

```css
*{
 margin : 0;
 padding : 0;
 font-family: Century Gothic;
}

.login {
 width: 320px;
 height: 420px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 background: rgba(139,0,139, 0.7);
 color: #fff;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 70px 30px;
}

h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 40px;
}

.login p{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-weight: bold;

}

.login input{
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.login input[type="text"], input[type="uuid"]{
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 background: transparent;
 outline: none;
 height: 40px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px; 


}

.login #myBtn {
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 height: 40px;
 width: 260px;
 background: #fb2525;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.login #myBtn:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #ffc107;
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
    <h1>Login Here!</h1>
    <form>
     <p>License</p>
     <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter License">
     <p>UUID</p>
     <input type="uuid" name="" placeholder="Enter UUID with '-'">
     <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Login</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
     // Get the button
     var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

     function myFunction() {
        const url = '';
        print("hi");
        $.get(url, function(data, status){
         console.log("hi")
        })
     }
    </script>
   </div>
```

Comment: When using the script tag, you shouldn't put actual code in when you are also using the `src` parameter. So just put two in there, one for the code and one for the src

Comment: **Danger**: [jQuery 3.3.1 has known security vulnerabilities](https://snyk.io/test/npm/jquery/3.3.1); upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)